# WebClient DownloadFile access denied

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, server, web-client

I'm trying to download the file to the server, but instead data is written to the error. Please tell me what is wrong. When i use this code on "http://localhost:xxx" everything is working fine. 
`WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
myWebClient.DownloadFile(remoteUri, Server.MapPath("~/test/" + "test.xml"));`

I updated my question. Here is my full code:

```
string path1 = "certificate1.p12";
string path2 = "certificate2.crt";
X509Certificate2 cert1 = new X509Certificate2(Server.MapPath(("~/test/") + path1), "", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
X509Certificate2 cert2 = new X509Certificate2(Server.MapPath(("~/tets/") + path2));
CertificateWebClient2 myWebClient = new CertificateWebClient2(cert1, cert2);
string remoteUri = "https://xxxxx";
string path = "test.xml";
myWebClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
myWebClient.DownloadFile(remoteUri, Server.MapPath((@"~/Files/") + path));


public class CertificateWebClient : WebClient
{
    private readonly X509Certificate2 certificate1;
    private readonly X509Certificate2 certificate2;

    public CertificateWebClient(X509Certificate2 cert1, X509Certificate2 cert2)
    {
        certificate1 = cert1;
        certificate2 = cert2;
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(Object obj, X509Certificate X509certificate, X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors errors)
        {
            return true;
        };

        request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
        request.Method = "Post";
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        request.ContentLength = 0;
        request.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate1);
        request.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate2);
        return request;
    }
}
```

Comment: show the error please

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the download is blocked by your proxy server. If so, use the following code:

```
using (var webClient = new WebClient())
{
    //  Obtain the 'Proxy' of the  Default browser.
    IWebProxy webProxy = webClient.Proxy;

    if (webProxy != null)
    {
        // Use the default credentials of the logged on user.
        webProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    }

   // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, this is not helping me

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are not using credentials. When you load with the browser it is automatically appending it, but not the webclient.

So you need to use default credentials.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.usedefaultcredentials(v=vs.110).aspx

But the web server should use the proper user.

Answer (score 0):

Try with default credentials.

```
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient { UseDefaultCredentials = true };
myWebClient.DownloadFile(remoteUri, Server.MapPath("~/test/" + "test.xml"));
```